# C# program for guessing coin toss

Tags: c#, loops

I'm a beginner with programming so any hints would be greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to create a program where the user guesses whether a **'coin toss'** will produce **heads (0)** or **tails (1)** using a random number generator and a loop as the 'coin'.  The program must output the **percent of correct guesses out of the total games played.**

I've tried many different ways and it's far from right! It's v discouraging.

Thanks in advance for any tips!!
-C

This is basically the closest I've come:

```
    for (numPlays = 0; ; numPlays++)
        {
            Console.Write("\nWrite H/h to guess Heads, T/t to guess Tails, or Q/q to quit =>  ");
            userChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            if (userChoice == 'H' || userChoice == 'h')
            {
                if (compChoice == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYOU WON");
                    numWins++;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYOU LOSE");

                if (userChoice == 'Q' || userChoice == 'q')
                    if (compChoice == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nYOU WON");
                        numWins++;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("\nYOU LOSE");

                if (userChoice == 'q' || userChoice == 'Q')
                {
                    percentWin = (double)(numWins / numPlays);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou won {0} out of {1} game(s) or {2:P} of the games played.", numWins, numPlays, percentWin);
                }
           }

        }

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your code is doing and why it isn't what you want?

Comment: Where is the computer making it's choice? Also, what does compChoice being 0 or 1 actually mean? (And why is compChoice not boolean?)

Comment: Do you have any specific problem? By the way, always put your brackets, your if-else statements are pretty messy and really error-prone. If you do not have any specif problem and only want tips, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate.

Comment: you forgot to tell your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I optimized your code a little bit,I hope this helps:

```
int numPlays = 0, numWins = 0;
int compChoice = 0;
char userChoice;
double percentWin;
Random rnd = new Random();
while (true)
{
     Console.Write("\nWrite H/h to guess Heads, T/t to guess Tails, or Q/q to quit =>  ");
     userChoice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
     compChoice = rnd.Next(0, 2);
     if (char.ToLowerInvariant(userChoice) != 'q')
     {
           if (char.ToLowerInvariant(userChoice) == 'h' && compChoice == 0)
           {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYOU WON");
                numWins++;
           }
           else if (char.ToLowerInvariant(userChoice) == 't' && compChoice == 1)
           {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYOU WON");
                numWins++;
           }
           else
           {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYOU LOSE");
           }
           numPlays++;
     }
     else
     {
           percentWin = (double) numWins/numPlays;
           Console.WriteLine("\nYou won {0} out of {1} game(s) or {2:P} of the games played.", numWins, numPlays, percentWin);
           break;
     }

}
```

I think you don't need an explanation, all of the code is self-explanatory.But you have an obvious mistake when you calculating the percentage:

```
 percentWin = (double)(numWins / numPlays);
```

Here you are performing an `integer` division,then casting that result to `double`,it's *pointless* because you already lose your *decimal points*.Instead you should cast one of the operands to `double` so it will perform a double division and you will get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke this method and play your game!

```
    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("\nWrite H/h to guess Heads, T/t to guess Tails, or Q/q to quit =>  ");
        char userChoice;
        int numWins = 0;
        int numPlays = 0;
        double percentWin = 0d;
        while ((userChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine())).ToString().ToLower() != "q")
        {
            numPlays++;

            int compChoice = new Random().Next(2);

            if (userChoice == 'H' || userChoice == 'h')
            {
                if (compChoice == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYOU WON");
                    numWins++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYOU LOSE");
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (userChoice == 'T' || userChoice == 't')
            {
                if (compChoice == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYOU WON");
                    numWins++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYOU LOSE");
                }
                continue;
            }                        
        }

        if (numPlays != 0)
        {
            percentWin = (double)numWins / numPlays;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou won {0} out of {1} game(s) or {2:P} of the games played.", numWins, numPlays, percentWin);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: if user type more than one character, your solution will blow up.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I tried to write according to @user3335589 requirement. Its definitely not a general solution.

Answer (score -2):

This should not be any difficult, you just need to make a clear algorithm

Let me suggest one

```
Char playOrExit= 'y'
Int32 gameCount = 0;
Int32 Wins = 0;
While (playOrExit.ToUpper.Equals('Y'))
{
Console.Write("Press Y to continue playing and N to exit");
playOrExit = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
//Computer choice will be math.random from 0 and 1
//now take user choice
//compare and show if he won or lost
}
if(gameCount >0)
{
Console.WriteLine("\nYou played {0} times, out of which {1} game(s) were won.",  gameCount,Wins);
}
```